# Video call using PJSUA

Tags: visual-c++, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm using pjsua to create a video call from a monitor to a phone. I'm able to establish an audio call without problem, but if I try to establish a video call (`vid_cnt=1`), I'm getting an error.

My purpose is to get and save the audio and video of the phone.

This is my configuration:

```
void hard_account_config(pjsua_acc_config& acc_cfg, pjsua_transport_id transport_tcp) {
    pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg);
    
    acc_cfg.ka_interval = 15;

    // VIDEO
    acc_cfg.vid_in_auto_show = PJ_TRUE;
    acc_cfg.vid_out_auto_transmit = PJ_TRUE;
    acc_cfg.vid_cap_dev = VideoCaptureDeviceId();
        acc_cfg.vid_wnd_flags = PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_BORDER | PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_RESIZABLE;

    acc_cfg.reg_timeout = 300;
    acc_cfg.use_srtp = PJMEDIA_SRTP_DISABLED;

    pjsua_srtp_opt_default(&acc_cfg.srtp_opt);

    acc_cfg.ice_cfg_use = PJSUA_ICE_CONFIG_USE_CUSTOM;
    acc_cfg.ice_cfg.enable_ice = PJ_FALSE;
    acc_cfg.allow_via_rewrite = PJ_FALSE;
    acc_cfg.allow_sdp_nat_rewrite = acc_cfg.allow_via_rewrite;
    acc_cfg.allow_contact_rewrite = acc_cfg.allow_via_rewrite ? 2 : PJ_FALSE;
    acc_cfg.publish_enabled = PJ_TRUE;
    
    acc_cfg.transport_id = transport_tcp;

    acc_cfg.cred_count = 1;
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_string(USER);
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_string("*");
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_string("Digest");
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
    acc_cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_string(PASS);
}
```

Once registration is completed, I run the following code:

```
prn("=== Test Call ===");
pj_str_t uri = pj_string("sip:" + call_target + "@" + SERVER);

pjsua_call_id call_id;
pjsua_call_setting call_setting;
pjsua_call_setting_default(&call_setting);
call_setting.flag = 0;
call_setting.vid_cnt = PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO ? 1 : 0;

pjsua_msg_data msg_data;
pjsua_msg_data_init(&msg_data);
pj_status_t status = pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &uri, &call_setting, NULL, &msg_data, &call_id);
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) { 
    prn("Error trying: pjsua_call_make_call"); 
    return;
}
```

I know that `PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO` is equal to 1 on the conf_site.h and `pjsua_call_make_call` return PJ_SUCCESS.

I've seen that if I have headphones connected, there is no problem. But if I disconnect them, the following error is shown:
`#pjsua_aud.c  ..Error retrieving default audio device parameters: Unable to find default audio device (PJMEDIA_EAUD_NODEFDEV) [status=420006]`
If I connect the headphones, I enable the video and run my code, the following error is shown:
`#pjsua_media.c  ......pjsua_vid_channel_update() failed for call_id 0 media 1: Unable to find default video device (PJMEDIA_EVID_NODEFDEV)`

So, using PJSUA it is necessary to have audio and video devices on the monitor and phone? Should I create virtual ports if I don't have the devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to get a list of audio/video devices in PJSUA, which will most likely provide you with a loopback device (among others).

```c
  pjmedia_aud_dev_info audio_device[64];
  unsigned int audio_device_cnt = 64;
  status = pjsua_enum_aud_devs(audio_device, &audio_device_cnt);
  printf("There are %d audio devices\n", audio_device_cnt);
  for (int i = 0; i < audio_device_cnt; i++) {
      printf("%d: %s\n", i, audio_device[i].name);
  }

  pjmedia_vid_dev_info video_device[64];
  unsigned int video_device_cnt = 64;
  status = pjsua_vid_enum_devs(video_device, &video_device_cnt);
  printf("There are %d video devices\n", video_device_cnt);
  for (int i = 0; i < video_device_cnt; i++) {
      printf("%d: %s\n", i, video_device[i].name);
  }
```

I have not personally tried capturing a loopback audio device but for video, PJSUA provides an internal colorbar generator (`Colorbar generator` in this list), which you can use.

Once you find the indices of loopback or dummy audio/video devices you want to use, you can set them by using

```c
pjsua_set_snd_dev(<YOUR DUMMY CAPTURE DEVICE>, <YOUR DUMMY PLAYBACK DEVICE>);   

acc_cfg.vid_cap_dev = <YOUR VIDEO CAPTURE DEVICE>;
```